# Correct Schema.org for user-generated social media content

Tags: schema.org, social-media

I'm a server-side developer dabbling in structured data (Schema.org) for the first time.

The web application I'm developing contains user generated "topics" in which said users can submit bite-sized text/image posts associated to the topic. It's kind of a cross between Reddit and Twitter.

I want to lace the HTML template files with relevant structured data.

My question is quite rudimentary:

Should I mark out the `body` as  `itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog"` and each user's submission as `itemprop="blogPosts" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting"`?

It's not really a traditional blogging website, so I was wondering what industry experts would have done if they were in my shoes.

Comment: If you only want to add structured data because you want to get rich results in search engines, you have to follow each search engine’s documentation for the rich result. In that case, please reference the rich result(s) you want to get -- you can then ask if, or how, your pages could qualify for this rich result. --- The alternative is to ask what the best Schema.org representation would be for your content, but that doesn’t necessarily enable rich results.

Comment: @unor: thanks for the nuanced insight. So if I'm just focused on the best schema.org representation for a web app like mine, do you suggest `http://schema.org/Blog` and its related attributes to be the right schema? Or any other comes to mind as well? How would you have done this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it’s not a blog post (`BlogPosting`), I would suggest to use the parent type [`SocialMediaPosting`](https://schema.org/SocialMediaPosting):

> A post to a social media platform, including blog posts, tweets, Facebook posts, etc.

There is no equivalent for [`Blog`](https://schema.org/Blog), though, but that’s not necessary anyway:

- **If there is one page per topic, and all posts appear on this page,** you could use [`WebPage`](https://schema.org/WebPage) with [`about`](https://schema.org/about) (for representing the topic) and [`hasPart`](https://schema.org/hasPart) (for referencing each `SocialMediaPosting`).
- **If each post appears on its own page,** you could use [`ItemPage`](https://schema.org/ItemPage) with [`mainEntity`](https://schema.org/mainEntity) (for referencing the `SocialMediaPosting`), and in the `SocialMediaPosting`, you could use `about` (to reference the topic, which could be represented on its own page).

If these aren’t really topics the posts are *about*, but more like categories/sections the posts belong to, you could use [`articleSection`](https://schema.org/articleSection) instead of `about`.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful alternatives unor!

Comment: Quick question: would utilizing a `CollectionPage` instead of `WebPage` make more sense in a scenario like this? Each `topic page` can be likened to a collection of social-media postings about the given topic, so that's why I figured maybe this more specific type would be a good fit.

Comment: @HassanBaig: I went with `WebPage`, because I wasn’t sure what the focus on such a topic page is. If the focus is on the posts, the `CollectionPage` type makes sense. But if the focus is on the topic, I think it’s not a good match, and neither is `ItemPage` (because, next to the topic, there are also the posts), so `WebPage` seems to be the safest choice in that case.

Comment: Well, it's quite "post" focused, and the topic is just there to contextualize the posts. Moreover, posts themselves need not be opinions solely, they can be content (e.g. a large part of our users love posting poetry). So I fathom `CollectionPage` it is?

Comment: @HassanBaig: Yes, I would go with `CollectionPage` then, for the topic pages.

Comment: Cool, thanks! Lastly, every post also has a comments section under it, so I'm deducing I'd use `https://schema.org/Comment` to tag that, correct?

Comment: @HassanBaig: Yes, with the [`comment`](https://schema.org/comment) property on `SocialMediaPosting`: `comment` `Comment`